# Reg : Button Validation

Tags: apex, custom-button, button

I have a button it have to work only when opportunity is won = true and shipping address is blank i wrote the button code but it is not working.Can anyone help what i did mistake in my code.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/15.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/15.0/apex.js")}
if({!Opportunity.IsWon} == true &&{!IF(ISBlank{!Opportunity.ShippingAddress__c})})
{
sforce.apex.execute("create","createMethod",{oppId:"{!Opportunity.Id}"});
alert("create");
}
else
{
 alert("not create")
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following and this will work:

```
if(({!Opportunity.IsWon}) && {!ISBLANK(Opportunity.ShippingAddress__c)})
```

Answer (score 0):

Why did you put the two if conditions?

Put only one IF but two conditions like

`if(({!Opportunity.IsWon} == true) && {!Opportunity.ShippingAddress__c} == '')
{
sforce.apex.execute("create","createMethod",{oppId:"{!Opportunity.Id}"});
alert("create");
}`

Update:

Try to update it REQUIRESCRIPT with below versions

`{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/30.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/30.0/apex.js")}`

Hope this might helps....

Comment: @Subhash- it saved but when i click on button it showing me an error like problem occur with javascript button.As per my business i need to check 2 condtions when 2 conditions is true at that i have to send opp id to my class

Comment: Check my update...

Comment: same error. and showing like isblank is not defiend also

Comment: Any other way.to resolve this issue

Comment: Check my code now...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41240/discussion-between-sathya-and-subhash).